# How do I tune a low frequency series resonant circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, resonance

I am driving a 2.2mH inductor and 736pF cap at 125kHz with a h-bridge trying to make a resonant circuit. My power source is 2.5V. Man, I am having a lot of trouble. I can get to 20V p-p in a signal generator setup driving the h-bridge but only 8V p-p when I solder in the same 1% caps on a uC prototype. I have seen advice on trimmers but I am interested in a digital solution or auto tuning. Does anyone have a schematic of fet switched bank of caps so I could what it looks like? Could I do it with only 2.5V available for the fets? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resonant circuit in your uC prototype is detuned compared to your signal generator set-up. So your 1% capacitors aren't a good match anymore.

The inductor will interact heavily with all metals (pcb material) around it and will change its inductivity. Also if your inductor gets charged up part of the magnetic field will create eddy currents in the nearby metals. This leaks energy out of your resonant circuit lowering the output voltage.

As for automatic tuning: I researched different methods over the last month for an RFID project and didn't found anything practical.

The most promising way was using varicap diodes to do the tuning but they only work if the voltage within your resonant tank stays relative low. Otherwise the signal swing itself will detune the varicaps and you end up with a non-linear system.

I suggest that you keep tuning your circuit by changing the capacitor until you hit the resonant frequency. If you have access to a network analyzer you can directly measure the current resonant frequency and calculate the required capacitance. That gets you close but you'll likely have to add or remove a few picofarads as the analyzer will have a detuning effect itself.

Without such measuring equipment it's harder but still doable. Change the capacitance a bit and observe the output voltage. If it goes up you've moved closer to the resonant frequency. If it drops lower the capacitor instead. With ten iterations or so you should get close to your resonant frequency.

(I'd start by removing capacitance because it's likely that your inductance went up).

Be prepared to redo this step each time you add or remove metal to your device. E.g. if you add for example batteries to your prototype expect your tuning to drift away again.

Answer (score 0):

A 2.2mH inductor + 736pF capactor is one hell of a Quality factor (would be about 10k with 10 Ohm serie resistance - physicaly impossible).

$$ Q = 2/R*\sqrt{L/C} $$
with L,C & R the pure inductance, pure capacitance and total serie resistance of the tank.

High quality factor doesn't make your life easier :

1. extremely narow bandwith makes it easy to detune the circuit. Inductor temperature increase is usualy sufficient to change the inductance enough for de-tuning.
2. you need an High Q inductor (which is hard to find in the mH range) otherwise the inductor quality factor will determinate both the total Q *AND* the resonnant frequency trough added parasitic capacitance. A 2.2mH inductor may have well above 100pF parallel capacitance
3. If the tank is loaded, the load current will be able to change the practical resonannt frequency (similar to what happens in LLC converters)

If you have to use this tank and cannot change the L-C ratio you can indeed consider driving a  bank of capacitor with super logic level fets (0.8V threshold). Beware that super logic level FET are harder to build with increasing blocking voltage so you won't find many above 60V Vds max. This migth be the limiting factor because they will have to block the peak to peak voltage of the resonnant cap.